# What is the major difference between Data mining and Data warehousing

Tags: computer-science, data-mining, data-warehouse

Data mining and Data warehousing are inter-related but yet different areas in the field of Computer sciences. What is the major difference between these two and how they are related to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Data mining: *advanced* analysis. Avoid SQL databases (as well as most NoSQL, because key-value stores and columnar stores are just as useless here), they are very slow and way too limited.

Data warehousing: OLAP, with very little analytical capabilities. Some basic filtering (drill down) and averaging. Here, columnar layouts are nice, because they allow computing average values efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

Data Warehousing is putting data in a central location in a way that is optimised for querying and analysis, i.e. it is more structured towards reporting and analysis than a 'live' system both in terms of performance and usability.

Data Mining is using advanced analytical techniques on any data (perhaps even that stored in a data warehouse), typically using maths and statistics-based approaches.